# laravel facebook api FacebookRedirectLoginHelper error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel

I've installed the facebook api via composer.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0.

And I have a controller with this code

```
<?php

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

class FacebookController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {


        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxx','xxx');

        // Use one of the helper classes to get a FacebookSession object.
        //   FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
        //   FacebookCanvasLoginHelper
        //   FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper
        // or create a FacebookSession with a valid access token:
        $session = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://test.dev/index.php/facebook');

        // Get the GraphUser object for the current user:

        try {
          $me = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 'GET', '/me'
          ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
          echo $me->getName();
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
          // The Graph API returned an error
            echo '<h2>Exception 1</h2>';
            echo '<pre>' , print_r($e) , '</pre>';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
          // Some other error occurred
            echo '<h2>Exception 2</h2>';
            echo '<pre>' , print_r($e) , '</pre>';
        }
    }


}
```

But when I try and run the code I get an error and the following in the laravel.log file

```
[2014-07-15 17:45:20] production.ERROR: exception 
'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper' not found' in /var/www/app/controllers/FacebookController.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Has anyone here successfully used the facebook php api library with laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add

```
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
```

Which got rid of that error.